# Is there a way to provide access in Jenkins for script approvals to non admin users?

Tags: jenkins

We cannot provide admin access to all users but need a way to provide script approval access to Non admin users? Any ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

At first this [page](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/) about script-approval could be helpful.
Back to the main topic I thing the best way to achieve this is use [Matrix based security Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) - `RunScripts` option in `Overall` section. 
Or You can always auto-approve" scripts with the [Permissive Script Security Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin). So it's depends on security policies in your organization.